# Is Rogue's power absorption ability limited to just the skin on her hands?

Tags: marvel, x-men, rogue

In the X-Men movies whenever Rogue touched someone she would temporarily get their powers. And that is why she had to wear gloves all the time, but what I'm wondering is was it only her hands that had this "power"? Or could any part of her body come in contact with another mutant and gain their ability?

Comment: I thought in one of the movies (not sure how canon they are) she inadvertently does this with a kiss.

Comment: @NickT: it's the first X-Men movie, and it's the scene where we're introduced to Rogue.

Comment: How often do you touch random strangers with _not your hands_?  ;)

Comment: @Izkata Are you implying you never accidentally bump into people or don't get crowded on a bus?

Comment: @Dason Often, really.  I was referencing the "skin" part of the question, since it seemed phrased oddly, and that it was more likely we don't see it ever happen because skin-to-skin contact with strangers is rare when the hands aren't involved.

Comment: @Dason Wouldn't you be properly dressed when "bumping" into someone? So skin contact may not occur.

Comment: If I'm wearing short sleeves there could easily be arm to arm contact.

Comment: @Martha She also kisses Iceman (in one of the later movies), when he's using a layer of ice to protect himself (and then gets in strife when it melts).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rogue's mutant ability wasn't confined to her hands, but her entire skin.

According to the [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Rogue)

> Rogue is a mutant who formerly possessed the ability to absorb the memories, abilities, personality, and outward physical characteristics of other beings through skin-to-skin contact. Such transfers lasted for 60 times longer than the contact time, with extended contact resulting in the possibility of permanent absorption. No upper limit had been determined for the number of beings Rogue could simultaneously imprint.
>   Upon absorbing another's memories, Rogue also gained any associated emotional responses. Rogue was typically able to control such emotions, however absorbing psyches more powerful than her own resulted in Rogue’s psyche being supplanted.

Answer (score 5):

In the X-Men movies, Rogue's power was to steal the life force from anyone she had skin to skin contact with.  In the case of another mutant, she also stole their power.  I believe the only one capable of surviving prolonged contact with her was Wolverine.